# libqtchartsqml2plugin.so: (libQt6ChartsQml.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

Tags: qt, charts, qml, pyqt6

I installed `Python 3.10.5` and `Qt 6.2.3` and I also installed `PyQt6-Charts and PyQt6`.

I can easily compile simple pyqt and qml applications.

like this:

in `main.py` :

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QUrl
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(
        handle_object_created, Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection
    )
    engine.load(url)

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and in `main.qml` :

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: root

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("test Page")

}
```

But as I add `ChartView` I got this error :

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtCharts

Window {
    id: root

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("test Page")

    ChartView {
        id: line
        x: 53
        y: 77
        width: 300
        height: 300
        LineSeries {
            name: "LineSeries"
            XYPoint {
                x: 0
                y: 2
            }

            XYPoint {
                x: 1
                y: 1.2
            }

            XYPoint {
                x: 2
                y: 3.3
            }

            XYPoint {
                x: 5
                y: 2.1
            }
        }
    }



}
```

> QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
> file:///home/parisa/pychart/main.qml:3:1: Cannot load library
> /home/parisa/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt6/qml/QtCharts/libqtchartsqml2plugin.so:
> (libQt6ChartsQml.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory)

[image]

My `libQt6ChartsQml.so` path**:**`/home/parisa/Applications/Qt/6.2.3/gcc_64/lib`

[image]

and the `libqtchartsqml2plugin.so` path is `/home/parisa/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt6/qml/QtCharts`

[image]

Comment: The error message says it: `libQt6ChartsQml.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` -> You need to install that library correctly. First things first, does it work through C++?

Comment: @LászlóPapp , yes it works correctly with c++ or qml. This happens only in pyqt

Comment: To localise the issue, does it help if you put the location of libQt6ChartsQml.so in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as a quick check?

Comment: How can I do that? I use Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Check where in Qt `libQt6ChartsQml.so` is installed to, and then `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$that_location:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: @LászlóPapp do you mean `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$/home/parisa/Applications/Qt/6.2.3/gcc_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ? or `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$/home/parisa/Applications/Qt/6.2.3/gcc_64/lib:/home/parisa/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt6/qml/QtCharts` ?

Comment: I meant what I wrote. You could break the application by executing your idea of the second.

Comment: @LászlóPapp I install `PyQtChart-Qt5-5.15.2` (pip install PyQtChart) like I installed  PyQt6-Charts and PyQt6 (pip install PyQt6-Charts PyQt6) and it works and my program compiled but as I try it with `PyQt6` I got that error and I didn't understand why. I didn't understand how should I write the export command.

Comment: It is literally just  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/parisa/Applications/Qt/6.2.3/gcc_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`